# Control IOPS in a multi-tenant hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop

Today's schedulers model the map/reduce slots more based on diving MEM/CPU based on cores..however what kind of fencing techniques can be used to ensure IOPS be controlled thereby i mapper not taking over IO.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about hadoop capabilities to do so. Have to be noted that Yarn which is all about resource management today is capable to take into account only memory.
I would try to speculate why so: 
a) It is hard to predict how much IO/CPU needed for the job. Without knowing it - it will be impossible to limit 
b) Scheduling problem taking into account several types of resources will be much harder

Comment: I was wondering how Amazon is able to guarantee IOPS while scheduling VM's in their cloud.

Comment: In general they do not and you observe serious fluctuation of performance. What they do is throttling - suppressing IOPS for users who actively use it. Although recently they have instances with provisioned IOPS - i didn't check the quality.